# How to resize a fixed width and height UIImageView with auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view named `myView` which is always half the screen and sit at the top of screen.

Inside this view I added an `UIImageView` with 120x120 size which sits in center of the `myView` (horizontally and vertically). Inside the IB, to satisfy the constraints(X & Y) I always need to set a fixed width and height for my image, after I set center horizontally and center vertically.

But with a fixed height and width, the image doesn't resize when changing the screen size. I want my image to resize when running on iPhone5 or iPhone 4s, because `myView` will resize. 
I need something like the image should depend on the `myView` size.

How to actually achieve this ?

Comment: have you tried setting contentMode of imageView? imageView.contetnMode = UIVIewContentModeAspectFill;

Comment: Yes, but I think because the height and width are fixed, it won't change anything.

Comment: u can do this using auto layout...but may be a bit messy...
Simply you can set the outlet of the fixed height and width constraint..then set it programmatically...in the viewWillAppear() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set `imageView.clipToBounds = yes`, and also set `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

**Update**
You are talking about imageView not the image, in that case it will not resize due to constant width and height, do one thing, create IBoutLet of constraint and change there values when required, or you can also set Aspect ratio with superView

Comment: It doesn't resize, I guess it's because of fixed width and height.

Comment: Okay, if you are taking about imageView not the image then it will not resize

Comment: Ok, if I choose aspect ration with superview, it will give me a 2:5 ratio. But I still need to give it more constraints to the imageview. For me, leading/trialing/bottom/top seems to not work. It always ask me for X and Y constraint. Any idea what more constraints I can give to the imageview ?

Comment: If you are using leading, top, bottom  and trailing then remove height and width constraint and it will work....

Comment: Its not working, the imageview doesn't even appear on the screen anymore. Very strange, in the view I also have a label and some buttons, maybe they are affecting it.

Comment: I managed to add constraints like proportional width and height to superview, by changing the Multiplier value. And also setting center to X and Y. Now it appears in the center, but it's no longer a circle. It looks like it is pushed from the sides. And there is no auto layout error.

Comment: Chnage radius value inside viewdidlayoutsubviews imageView.layer.cornerRadius=width/2

Comment: I am already doing that, but in viewDidLoad. Want to discuss this on chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87179/discussion-between-c-x-and-adrian).

Comment: literally just spent an hour trying to manually update the `Constant` value of two NSLayoutConstraints (one for width, one for height), without any progress and the `contentMode` was the answer. i would upvote this 5 times if i could.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image with fixed width and height it will not change respectively.
You can either set it to be relative to `myView` or you can instead set leading and trailing size from all for edges and delete the center constrains.

Comment: How can I set it to be relative to myView ?

Comment: You need to play with the constrains it should take much time. you can also set fixed trailing and leading space would create similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should look like this:

[image]

Comment: If I do this, it will say for example leading and trailing = 240 , because of the free form of the storyboard, which is much bigger then the screen. And then when running, my image view disappears from the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand your layout, maybe you can attach a screenshot? @Adrian

Comment: Its exactly your layout from the screenshot., but the image view is much smaller and in the center of the view. The size of the storyboard is Inferred. Which is much wider than the screen size when running in simulation.

Comment: @Adrian No problem, change view size from **inferred** to any **iphone**. And then establish constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 4: Updating answer of @Adnan Aftab

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```